# Rstudio from zip : unable to establish connection to R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using Rstudio from zip for Windows 7 64. I have installed R 3.4.2 after uninstalling all previous versions of R and Rstudio. Now when I start Rstudio from the bin folder in the zip archive it cannot connect to R and gives me an error after a while saying

> unable to establish connection to R

Her is my `sesssionInfo()`

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2
```

Are there any settings I should look at? I suspect this is caused by the change I recently did / uninstalling previous versions and using the zip archive and so RStudio cannot point the the new version of R. How can I tell Rstudio where to find R?

Comment: Maybe try to delete the file `desktop.ini`. For me, this file is in the folder `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\RStudio`. I'm not sure, so do not delete it, rather move it somewhere in case that does not work so that you can move it back. You can also try to edit the contents of this file to set the path to R.

Comment: Thank you. I removed both `~\AppData\Roaming\RStudio` and `~\AppData\Local\RStudio`. I think it was the `local` folder that was the issue because it had a lot of stuff from the previous installs. Now I think the issue is because the previous version was Rstudio 1.0.153 and the new one i am using from zip is 1.1.383 is major update is what caused the issue.

Comment: It worked for one time only and then it stopped working. It created new folders in Roaming and Local appdata folders. I'm just going to go back to the old version